# javascript code formatting in eclipse doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, formatting

javascript code formatting doesn't work at all in eclipse under xubuntu.
Same problems with auto-completion and with validation. 
I tried different way to install Eclipse and its different  plugins nodeclipse, tern, jsdt ... 
I tried to open file with different editors. 
I tried to change formatting profile.
But everywere everything just doesn't work. 
It perfectly works for C/C++. But javascript not. It look like something generally wrong  with my eclipse+javascript+node.js environment. But what?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try JSDT pluging?
https://eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/
It adds a JavaScript project type and perspective to the Eclipse Workbench as well as a number of views, editors, wizards, and builders.

Comment: Did you try add on your project : Web Page Suport -> Include Web Browser Library.

Comment: Yes I did. What I can copy-past to show? I mean which config or other file? What else I have to check? I spent more then day reinstalling and trying different plugins and editors

Comment: In previous post I mant I tried JSDT I didn't try "Web Page Suport -> Include Web Browser Library" But how it related with code formatting for javascript?

Comment: I thought that with "Include Web Browser Library" could helper the eclipse find the right way to dealing with it. What is your eclipse version?

Comment: Eclipse for JavaScript and Web Developers

Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800

Comment: Finally it start works with some .js files But it doesn't  work for other. And I still couldn't find regularity.

Comment: What kind of project is the file in, and where is it in relation to a source folder on the Include Path?

Comment: JavaScript project But I tried yo convert it in Tern project too. None of the features of the Tern works either.

Comment: Re "the Include Path" In project in Sources  the option "Include (All)" Excluded: \*\*/node_modules/\*, ... and couple more not important paths

Comment: In some cases JSDT fails to format file, especially if code uses newer js syntax. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357829

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse "JavaScript Editor" (from JSDT) always had some issues.
Formatting does work, but can break under some circumstances.

> The JavaScript-Plugin in Eclipse is buggy and evil since a few years.

Quota from: [Auto-formatting of JavaScript code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161604/auto-formatting-of-javascript-code-in-eclipse)

This is not just my opinion, this has been going on for years as the Eclipse community had a hard time catching up with the Java/JavaEE evolutions (and C/C++ and ...) in parallel to all the JavaScript changes.
I do not blame them as this is all for free !

The Eclipse JavaScript Editor (JSDT one) can 'choke' on various keywords for example: `myObject.import(xyz);` will break it (on some versions at least) due to the `import` keyword.
Sometimes I also noticed that some types of calculations involving divisions and many brackets broke the formatter. *Autocompletion* also has many issues, support is far from that of Java or C/C++.
It can also get slow due to code *folding*, but that can be disabled in `Editor/Folding` and *spell checking* which can also be disabled.

---

**Eclipse Wild Web Developer**

With the latest Eclipse releases since 2019 / 2020 you can use **Eclipse Wild Web Developer** (Red Hat is the main contributor):

- [Info](https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-wild-web-developer)
- [Install](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.wildwebdeveloper) or here [Github](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper#installation)

Background:

> Because of technical reasons (reimplementation of parsers mostly) and
> strategical priorities (Java EE), Eclipse IDE and the WebTools project
> have hard time catching up with innovation in the front-end Web
> development world. As a result, several editors for typical web
> languages (CSS, HTML, JavaScript...) shipped in the Simultaneous
> Release are of low quality compared to the state of the domain and
> competiting IDEs.

Yes we noticed ^^

> Eclipse Wild Web Developer integrates existing artifacts like TextMate
> grammars and Language Servers to provide a rich development experience
> to Web developers using typical programming languages for the Web
> (CSS, HTML, JSon, JavaScript, TypeScript...).
>
> Eclipse Wild Web Developer is about integrating existing technologies
> for those languages more than creating more specific language
> smartness.

That is a wise decision.
This reminds me of Unity vs Gnome in Ubuntu ... or various browsers ending up using Chromium. Maintaining your own stuff and keeping the pace is hard.